# Spring Security will not authenticate newly created users and throws NoResultException despite User confirmed to exist in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

The code for the entire project can be found @ https://github.com/dcechano/UniversityManagmentSystem

I am using Spring security 5 and Spring MVC project backed by custom dao authentication by a class an
implements `UserDetailsService`, namely `PersonService`. The entities are `Person`, `Student` and a few others that aren't relevant here. These entities are initialized using sql scripts and logging in with Spring security using these script initialized entities works fine.

However I have added functionality to save a new `Student` and store it in the H2 database. When I save them in the database and then go back and attempt to log in using this newly created `Student` (and `Person` by inheritance) Spring security refuses the authentication. Using the debugger I found that internally its throwing a `javax.persistence.NoResultFoundException` with message `No entity found for query`. But I have confirmed at several points throught that the new entity does indeed exist in the database. Below is my Spring Security Config class and some screenshots of me reproducing the problem and some results when running the debugger.

`SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private PersonService personService;

private CustomAuthentication customAuthentication;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**",
            "/static/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").hasAnyRole("STUDENT", "FACULTY_MEMBER", "STAFF_MEMBER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth")
            .successHandler(customAuthentication)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll();

}

@Bean
public CsrfTokenRepository repo() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repo = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repo.setParameterName("_csrf");
    repo.setHeaderName("X-CSRF-TOKEN");
    return repo;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(personService);
    auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return auth;
}

@Autowired
public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
    this.personService = personService;
}

@Autowired
public void setCustomAuthentication(CustomAuthentication customAuthentication) {
    this.customAuthentication = customAuthentication;
}
```

}

My `UserDetailsService` implementation. (`PersonRepo` extends `UserDetailsService`)

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private PersonRepo personRepo;

@Override
public Person findByUsername(String username) {
    return personRepo.findByUsername(username);
}

@Override
public void save(Person person) {
    personRepo.save(person);
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());
    logger.info("Inside the loadUserByUsername method");
    Person person = this.findByUsername(username);
    if (person == null) {
        logger.info("Person with username: " + username + " was not found!");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find Person with username " + username);
    }
    logger.info("User was successfully retrieved from database");
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityRoles = person.getRoles().stream().map(
            role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new User(person.getUsername(), person.getPassword(), grantedAuthorityRoles);
}

@Autowired
public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Autowired
public void setPersonRepo(PersonRepo personRepo) {
    this.personRepo = personRepo;
}
```

}

The MVC Mapping that stores the newly created `Student` in the database. Note the log statements.

```
@PostMapping("/save_student")
public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
    student.setUsername(student.getFirstName().charAt(0) + student.getLastName().toLowerCase());
    student.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(student.getPassword()));
    student.setRoles(List.of(roleRepo.getRoleByName(RoleEnum.ROLE_STUDENT.name())));
    student.setVersion(1);
    studentRepo.save(student);
    if (personService.loadUserByUsername(student.getUsername()) == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    } else {
        logger.info("Person with username " + student.getUsername() + " was indeed found.");
    }
    return "redirect:list_students";
}

@GetMapping("/list_students")
public String listStudents(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("students", studentRepo.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("people", personRepo.findAll());
    return "all_students";
}
```

These screenshots attempt to demo the bug. After I hit the register button it triggers the `@PostMapping("/save_student")` above where the new `Student` object is saved then redirected to a page that displays all `Person`s in the database. Not the new `Person` is listed.

[image: Registering new Student "Steve Miller"]

This is the screenshot of the logs that show that the new "Steve Miller" `Student` can be immediately retrieved after being saved.
[image: Log output showing that the new "Steve Miller" can be immediately retrieved]

The result after being redirected via the `@GetMapping(/list_students)`. Note that "Steve Miller" is listed.

[image: Note that "Steve Miller" is listed as a Person in the database]

Below is the debugger after attempting to log in under "Steve Miller". The break point is place in the `loadUserByUsername()` method from the `UserDetailsService` implimentation.

[image]

EDIT: Here are the links to the exception stacktrace and the entire server logs.
https://github.com/dcechano/UniversityManagmentSystem/blob/master/src/main/resources/authentication_failure_log.txt

https://github.com/dcechano/UniversityManagmentSystem/blob/master/src/main/resources/exception_stacktrace.txt

Comment: The logging nor the fact that it appears to exist doesn't say anything. Everything is done in a single `EntityManager` and results will be retrieved from the first level cache **not** the database. Your persons service appears not to be transactional (add `@Transactional`) for actually being able to persist something into  the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't realize this might be a chaching issue. Btw @Transactional is annotated on the actual repository method. How do I remedy this caching issue so that the new `Person` instance can be retrieved?

Comment: The code you have in your controller belongs in the service in a transactional method. That being said your last screenshot is totally unreadable and doesn't state what you say it should. Also which `loadByUsername` method? You have implemented it yourself so I assume it is calling that one? And are you sure the name is correct (and not simply the firstname?).

Comment: I moved the logic from the controller to the `PersonService` and annotated `save()` with `@Transactional` but the error is still happening. The `loadUserByUsername()` in the `PersonService` calls `this.loadByUsername` which calls `personRepo.loadByUsername()`, that method in the `PersonRepo` is annotated with `@Transactional`. I don't think this is a username issue because they are assigned programmatically and they correct username is being printed when all the `Person`s in the database are listed.

Comment: You are only lowercasing the first letter (why not everything?). I wasn't hinting at the generated username but the username you are using to login.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to your question as that indicates exactly where the error is coming from.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had to figure out how to configure logging. The stacktrace and the server logs are too long for StackOverflow to allow me to add them to my post. I added them to files and uploaded them to github. I provided links to the files at the end of my post. Please consider looking them over.